# In terminal node.js version is updated 18.17 but on our node.js app get v12.22.9

Tags: node.js, express

In terminal node.js version is updated 18.17 but on our node.js app get v12.22.9

How can i fix it anyone can help?

i have tried multiple solution still havent fixed the issue

i want to update my node.js app version also to get also 18.17 version.

anyone

Comment: Are you on windows or Mac?

Comment: Can you share (more) details of this `node.js app` ??

Comment: i am in windows  , also all dependency (node_modules are of version 12.22.9 which are not changing )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.